# Material UI Grid - Typescript Grid dynamically spacing warning

Tags: typescript, material-ui

Typescript give me an error about spacing value:

```sh
TS2322: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'boolean | 7 | 2 | 10 | 1 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 8 | "auto" | 9 | 11 | 12'.
No lint errors found
Version: typescript 3.5.2, tslint 5.14.0
```

Iterate on an array and set a `xl, lg, .. and so on`  prop dinamically:

```js
<Grid container spacing={2}>
  {row.map(resumeItem =>
     <Grid key={resumeItem.id} item xs={12} lg={6} xl={resumeItem.space}>
       ...
     </Grid>
   )}
</Grid>
```

Of course `space` property is a number!

Comment: Try `xl={resumeItem.space as any}` or `xl={resumeItem.space as 7}`

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are receiving this typescript error is because your `space` property allows *any* number, but the `xl` prop allows only a subset of numbers (specifically, any integer 1-12).  So for example, you could assign the number '17.2' to `space`, which would be a perfectly acceptable value for it, but would not be an acceptable value to assign to `xl`.

The best way to address this would be to change your type definition of `Number` for `space` to one that resembles that of the `xl` prop, i.e.

```
space: 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12
```

Of course, this could have some upstream implications depending on how you are assigning a value to it.

You could also do as suggested by the commenter and cast `space` as `any`... just note that what this is effectively doing is disabling type checking for this instance and you will lose the ability for Typescript to detect whether you're passing a possibly incompatible value to `xl`.  It's a tradeoff that only you can decide if it's worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all.
If i try to use this approach:

```js
space: 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12
```

The problem not resolve. If I use an an hoc interface not working too, so i'm using the `any` approach for the moment.

Thank you!